# What's wrong with this decoder? (in C#) - Help with padding extra bytes

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I have a PCX decoder here, written in C#, that is designed to return an IntPtr, which points to an array of uncompressed bytes (PCX files use RLE compression, but my decoder should be able to deal with this). I have already read the width, dimensions and palette from the file and the image will render just file as a bitmaps for most images, but some don't render correctly. The image is there and so are the colours, but the actual bitmap looks like it has been sliced diagonally 4 or 5 times and rearranged. I have checked the number of planes in the image and the bpp is fine too.

I assume it's something wrong with my code, so if anyone can see an error, could you let me know please.

---

EDIT 2:

As Guffa points out, I am not handling any padding. Could anyone point me in the right direction about this?

---

The code (sorry, there's quite a bit here, but it's the actual pixel-processor):

```
IntPtr pBits;
Boolean bRepeat;
Int32 RepeatCount;
Byte ReadByte;
Int32 Row = 0;
Int32 Col = 0;

Byte[] PCXData = new Byte[BytesPerScanline * ScanLines]; //BytesPerScanline * ScanLines);

BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(file);
r.BaseStream.Seek(128, SeekOrigin.Begin);

while (Row < ScanLines)
{
    ReadByte = r.ReadByte();
    bRepeat = (0xc0 == (ReadByte & 0xC0));
    RepeatCount = (ReadByte & 0x3f);

    if (!(Col >= BytesPerScanline))
    {
        if (bRepeat)
        {
            ReadByte = r.ReadByte();
            while (RepeatCount > 0)
            {
                PCXData[(Row * BytesPerScanline) + Col] = ReadByte;
                RepeatCount -= 1;
                Col += 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            PCXData[(Row * BytesPerScanline) + Col] = ReadByte;
            Col += 1;
        }
    }

    if (Col >= BytesPerScanline)
    {
        Col = 0;
        Row += 1;
    }
}

pBits = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocHGlobal(PCXData.Length);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(PCXData, 0, pBits, PCXData.Length);

return pBits;
```

Comment: Your naming convention (or lack thereof) makes the code harder to read. You are naming some local varaibles with hungarian notaion (which is discouraged in .NET), and other local variables like they were methods. Look for example at the code `ReadByte = r.Readyte()` where the result of the call to the method `ReadByte` is placed in the variable `ReadByte`...

Comment: Any particular reason you're using a `while` loop when you know the number of iterations per row and the number of rows to iterate over?  You should use a `for` loop intead.

Comment: Oh, well sorry about the Hungarian Notation, I wasn't familiar with it and I didn't know it was discouraged. As for the loop, doesn't it just do the same thing as a 'for' loop anyway?

Comment: @Danel DiPaolo: That's completely debatable and depends on situation, preference and conciseness.

Comment: How are you using the unpacked bytes? From your description of the problem, it sounds like you need some padding between scanlines to place each scanline on an even offset.

Comment: This could be the issue. The images it does work on seem to have even widths etc. How would I pad the scanlines?

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, you're not properly disposing of your unmanaged resources (e.g. BinaryReader).
Either call `r.Dispose()` after you're done with it, or wrap it in a using block, like this:

```
using(BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(file))
{
  ...
}
```

And always do this for any object that implements [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx).

Comment: OK, I thought I needed to dispose of it, but I haven't done much with binary reading for a while.

Comment: That is not the whole truth. BinaryReader/Writer, like StreamReader/Writer are helper classes for decoding the raw Stream bytes. When you Dispose a helper, it will dispose (close) the associated stream. This may in fact not be the desired behavior. One may want to control the lifetime of the associated stream independently. My advice here is to only Dispose a helper if the helper created the associated stream, otherwise Dispose the stream, not the helper.

Comment: @Tergiver: Yeh, I gathered that because when I tried it, it closed the stream and I use the same stream for several functions, so it wasn't appropriate for this.

Comment: [Addendum] My advice here is to only Dispose a helper if the helper created the associated Stream, *or you have transferred ownership of the Stream reference to the helper*, otherwise Dispose the stream, not the helper.

Comment: I disagree.  If it implements IDisposable, wrap it in a using block.